# Using AJAX/PHP/JS to report multiple status messages during a long process

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, wordpress

I understand that using PHP it isn't possible to send messages to the DOM using AJAX as the entire script must execute before the response becomes available. As such, it appears that I have two options:

1. Split the long process into several smaller ones and report back after each
2. Write status updates to a file and then have the system read the file as the process executes.

Are there any big advantages or disadvantages to either method?

Comment: What kind of process is this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood what methods are you questioning, but here is what you could do (using jQuery and PHP):

In javascript, use window.setTimeout(), to call function that uses ajax callback to check url.

URL is for php script, that checks if new message is present or not.

PHP script checks for new message either in flat tile or in db, not sure what you will use.

Script then prints message, either in straight html markup, or simple text, or in JSON or XML format.

On success, ajax call, outputs response to some selector on page, and calls again window.setTimeout().

this is part of html markup:

```
<div id="systemmessage">here goes new message</div>
```

this is part of javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.setTimeout('checkForMessages()',5000); //sets for 5 seconds.
});

function checkForMessages(){
$.ajax(function(){
 url: "checkformessages.php",
 success: function(data){
  if(data!=''){
    $('#systemmessage').html(data); //place response in systemmessage
  } 
  window.setTimeout('checkForMessages()',5000); //we set timeout again
 }
});

}
```

this is part of php script called i.e. "checkformessages.php":

```
$message = file_get_contents('messages.txt'); //check from file where you output new message 
//or
$message='';

//use db table, with fields id (int autoincrement, primary), message(text), user_id (integer), created(integer, strtotime - timestamp) 

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM system_messages WHERE user_id=somenumber AND created>(current time - 5 seconds)'; //this is more pseudo code, than correct syntax

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  $message.= $row->message.' <br/>';
}
}      

    if($message  && $message!=''){
    echo $messages; 
    }
```